# Add clickable checkbox to powerpoint slide on Mac

Tags: vba, checkbox, powerpoint, ms-office

I want to add a **clickable checkbox** (one or more) to a PowerPoint presentation slide. I'm using MacOS and Microsoft Office 365.

I guess that it is possible to do using macros created with VBA, but I have no idea what code needs to be created for this.

I would be very grateful if you would share the necessary code or suggest me another relevant ways to create clickable checkboxes in pptx under the Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes, labels, textboxes etc are all ActiveX features, and since ActiveX isn't supported on the Mac version of Office or in MacOS generally, you can't do this the way you would in Windows versions of Office.

You might be able to fake it by adding drawn rectangles and assigning a Run Macro action setting to each of them.

This page on the PPT FAQ that I maintain explains how to write the macro.
Determine which shape was clicked
https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00141_Determine_which_shape_was_clicked.htm

TL;DR - here's some sample code. This runs on both Windows and Mac (where bugs in PPT's VBA model force it to be more complicated than it would be otherwise):

```
Sub DoSomethingTo(oSh as Shape)

   Dim oSl as Slide
   Dim oShTemp as Shape

   ' oSh.Parent returns a valid reference to the shape's host slide:  
   Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(oSh.Parent.SlideIndex)

   ' and oSh.Name works:
   MsgBox oSh.Name

   ' So we use those two bits to get a reference 
   ' to the clicked shape like so
   Set oShTemp = oSl.Shapes(oSh.Name)
   With oShTemp
       .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oSh.Name
       ' and whatever else you want to do with the shape
   End With

End Sub
```